# Given Markov chain transition matrix, calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_1=3|X_2=1).$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, markov-chains

> Let $X_0,X_1,...$ be a 3-state Markov chain with transition matrix
>
> $$ \mathbf{P}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/3 & 1/3
>  & 1/3 \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> and initial distribution $\alpha=(1/2,0,1/2)$. Find
>
> (a) $\mathbb{P}(X_2=1|X_1=3)$
>
> (b) $\mathbb{P}(X_1=3,X_2=1)$
>
> (c) $\mathbb{P}(X_1=3|X_2=1)$
>
> (d) $\mathbb{P}(X_9=1|X_1=3,X_4=1,X_7=2)$

The book I'm using only has answers for odd numbered assignments, this is an odd so I want someone to check my results. Here is what I've done:

**(a)** Because of time-homogenity of Markov chains we have that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_2=1|X_1=3)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=1|X_0=3)=P_{31}=1/3.$$

**(b**) This is a joint distribution and because of Markov independence property we have that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=3,X_2=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_2=1|X_1=3)\mathbb{P}(X_1=3)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=1|X_0=3)\mathbb{P}(X_1=3)=P_{31}(\alpha P)_3.$$

We have that

$$=P_{31}(\alpha P)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/3 & 1/3
 & 1/3 \end{pmatrix}=\left(\frac{2}{9},0,\frac{2}{9}\right),$$

so the sought probability is $2/9$.

**(c)** Since $X_1$ does not depend on $X_2$, we have that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=3|X_2=1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1=3)=(\alpha P)_3=\frac{1}{3}.$$

**(d)** We have that time-homogenity and Markov properties gives

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_9=1|X_1=3,X_4=1,X_7=2)&=
\mathbb{P}(X_9=1|X_7=2)\mathbb{P}(X_7=2|X_4=1)\mathbb{P}(X_4=1|X_1=3)\\
&\times\mathbb{P}(X_1=3)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_2=1|X_0=2)\mathbb{P}(X_3=2|X_0=1)\mathbb{P}(X_3=1|X_0=3)\\
&\times\mathbb{P}(X_1=3)\\
&=P^2_{21}P^3_{12}P^3_{31}(\alpha P)_{3}
\end{align}$$

So we have that

\begin{align}
P^2&=\begin{pmatrix}2/3 & 1/6 & 1/6 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 4/9 & 5/18 & 5/18 \end{pmatrix}\implies P^2_{21}=0,\\
\end{align}

so it does not matter what $P^3$ is. Thus the answer is $0$. If this answer is correct, what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: (d) can be solved much more easily: by time homogeneity, the probability in question is the same as $P(X_{2}=1|X_{0}=2)$. In other words, the probability of transitioning from state $2$ to state $1$ in two steps. From state $2$, we can only go to state $1$, and from there we cannot remain at state $1$. So the probability is indeed $0$

Comment: @pwerth haha ofcourse. Its quite impressive how dull-minded one can be sometimes. Thanks. Do you think the other tasks are correctly solved as well?

Comment: Your (c) is wrong, of course $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for (a) is correct.

Your reasoning for (b) is correct, but you made an error in computing $\alpha P$. It should be $\left(1/6,5/12,5/12\right)$, and so the desired probability is $1/3\cdot5/12=5/36$.

As @Did pointed out, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent. Consider for example that on $\{X_2=1\}$, we have $\mathbb P(X_1=1)=0$. So for (c) we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_1=3\mid X_2=1) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X_1=3,X_2=1)}{\mathbb P(X_2=1)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb P(X_2=1\mid X_1=3)\mathbb P(X_1=3)}{\mathbb P(X_2=1)}\\
&=\frac{P_{31}(\alpha P)_3}{(\alpha P^2)_1}\\
&=\frac{1/3\cdot5/12}{5/9}\\
&=1/4.
\end{align}

As @pwerth pointed out, the probability for (d) is simply $P_{31}^2=0$.